# Lazy initialisation for method

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have a class with two private lists (initially empty) and a `Search` method that does some search in those lists. I want the lists to be initialized only once and thread safe.
Is there any construct in .NET similar to `Lazy<T>` for this scenario? I can put the `Init()` in a lock and have some flag to avoid duplicate initialization, or have `Lazy<List<int>>`for the lists. 
The logic for filling the lists is complex so there cannot be a separate method for each one

```cs
public class Myclass
{
    private static List<int> list1;
    private static List<int> list2;

    static bool init=false;
    private static object locker=new object();
    private static void Init()
    {
         lock(locker)
         {
           if(init)
             return;
            // fill list1,
            //fill list 2
            init=true;
         }
    }

    public static void Search(string query)
    {
        if(!init)
            Init();

        for(int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list2.Count; j++)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are already mentioning `Lazy<T>`. Does that not satisfy your requirements? If not, why?

Comment: @germi I have a void Init() that fills multiple collections.  What should I declare to Lazy<T>  lambda constructor of every collection?

Comment: Encapsulate all the things that should be lazy in a class, and use an instance of that class for `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: Do you need multiple instances of MyClass? If not you can use a thread-safe singleton pattern with lazy like described [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `private static readonly List<int> list1 = new List<int>();` that I don't know of?

Comment: What is the problem in this code I cant understand. It  seems thread safe for twice initialization. So If you dont update lists in another location. No need to effort more.

Comment: @wikiCan Yes it's fine, though the init flag is used in two methods (Init and Search) from different threads. I wonder if there was some out of the box .NET class to achieve this

Comment: I think no way to initialize twice. Also here you declared static members so there is no way to use multiple instance initialize. really strict only one instance and one init.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use a static constructor and do the initialization there? Really feels to me like things might be getting over complicated. As far as I know dot net will already make sure the constructor is run before any call to a static method executes.

Comment: And if you're going with this way the `init` bool probably needs to be `volatile` otherwise you might risk the filling of the lists being run multiple times with possibly even corruption due to non-thread-safe access.